# Intersection of a DataFrame slice and a list

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to select a subsection of a dataframe using .loc as such:

```
for date in months.index:
   labels = list(df.index.values)
   X = df.loc[(date - relativedelta(months=+3)):date.intersection(labels), ['A', 'B']]
   Y = df.loc[(date - relativedelta(months=+3)):date.intersection(labels), 'C']
   months.at[date, 'Prediction'] = forest.fit(X, Y)
```

I am following the method suggested at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike but am running into the error

```
AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'intersection'
```

Is this an issue because I am using a time-indexed dataframe, because I am intersecting with a slice of the dataframe and not the whole index, or another issue? I tried to convert the timestamps to datetime objects to no avail.

Comment: What is you goal here. To intersect columns a,b from 3 months previous to which date? Either way its what it says on the tin. `date.intersection(labels)` date has no intersection attribute.

Comment: I edited the code to be more clear. I'm looping through the months of the dataframe (the months df has the first day of the month as indices)

Comment: The question is what do I use instead, if I want to only select valid values? The problem is that the dataframe is missing some days so if I don't use something like 'intersection' it raises an error that says I'm passing something with missing labels to .loc.

Comment: Even if `date` was an index so you could call `date.intersection`... you can't use that as the stop of a slice, you need to slice with `.loc[date_start:date_stop, ...`

Comment: The df is indexed by dates. date_start is meant to be 3 months ago, and date_stop is meant to be the current date. I know that I have to call intersection on the slice itself, is there a way to do that? just putting parentheses around the slice doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import librarys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

#get today
today = datetime.datetime.now()

print(today)
```

output:

`datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 26, 20, 25, 40, 480870)`

Then work out the dates you want to work from, 90 days is easier.

```
#get date back 90 days
date_from = today - pd.to_timedelta(90,"D")

#create a mock DF

dates_this_year = pd.date_range("2020-01-01",datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
mock_values = np.arange(0,len(dates_this_year))
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":dates_this_year,"A":mock_values,"B":mock_values,"C":mock_values})
date_df = df.set_index("date")

date_df
```

output:

```
date        A   B   C       

2020-01-01  0   0   0
2020-01-02  1   1   1
2020-01-03  2   2   2
2020-01-04  3   3   3
2020-01-05  4   4   4
... ... ... ...
2020-08-22  234 234 234
2020-08-23  235 235 235
2020-08-24  236 236 236
2020-08-25  237 237 237
2020-08-26  238 238 238
```

Then to index it just use the date from and to.

`date_df.loc[date_from:today,["A","B"]]`

output:

```
date        A   B   
2020-05-29  149 149
2020-05-30  150 150
2020-05-31  151 151
2020-06-01  152 152
2020-06-02  153 153
... ... ...
2020-08-22  234 234
2020-08-23  235 235
2020-08-24  236 236
2020-08-25  237 237
2020-08-26  238 238
```